# how to write a for loop with a name with number in a neural network model?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am writing a neural network model using embedding method to categorical data.

```
    # Bind nulti_hot to embedding layer
    emb1 = keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=no_of_unique_cat(cat_data1), output_dim=embedding_size(cat_data1))(inp_cat_data1)
    emb2 = keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=no_of_unique_cat(cat_data2), output_dim=embedding_size(cat_data2))(inp_cat_data2)
    emb3 = keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=no_of_unique_cat(cat_data3), output_dim=embedding_size(cat_data3))(inp_cat_data3)
    emb4 = keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=no_of_unique_cat(cat_data4), output_dim=embedding_size(cat_data4))(inp_cat_data4)
    emb5 = keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=no_of_unique_cat(cat_data5), output_dim=embedding_size(cat_data5))(inp_cat_data5)
    emb6 = keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=no_of_unique_cat(cat_data6), output_dim=embedding_size(cat_data6))(inp_cat_data6)
    emb7 = keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=no_of_unique_cat(cat_data7), output_dim=embedding_size(cat_data7))(inp_cat_data7)
```

and afterwards, i flatten these embedded output

```
    flatten1 = keras.layers.Flatten()(emb1)
    flatten2 = keras.layers.Flatten()(emb2)
    flatten3 = keras.layers.Flatten()(emb3)
    flatten4 = keras.layers.Flatten()(emb4)
    flatten5 = keras.layers.Flatten()(emb5)
    flatten6 = keras.layers.Flatten()(emb6)
    flatten7 = keras.layers.Flatten()(emb7)
```

However, these two huge part causes my code to look redundant,
i wonder if i can use "for loop" to improve the simplicity for these 2 huge parts?

Comment: Use a list and a loop instead of individual varialbes... `embs = [keras.layers... for x in y]` and `flatten = [kera.layers... for emb in embs]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Want to make sure your cat_data1... cat_data7 and inp_cat_data1... Where did inp_cat_data7 get the variable or the string

```py
def get_embs(count):
    for i in range(1, count+1):
        cat_data = f"cat_data{i}"
        inp_cat_data = f"cat_data{i}"
        yield (keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=no_of_unique_cat(cat_data), output_dim=embedding_size(cat_data))(inp_cat_data))

def get_flattens():
    flattens = [keras.layers.Flatten()(emb) for emb in get_embs(10)]
```

This is a general code, but it is still necessary to clarify how your cat_data1 and inp_cat_data1 are generated. You may need to add the list at the source to facilitate the loop operation